# Automatically Disconnect Laptop internal keyboard on connecting External usb keyboard

Tags: keyboard

Is there Any way to Automatically Disconnect Laptop's internal keyboard on connecting an External usb keyboard ? I'm Using Ubuntu 18.04.2 Gnome edition .

Comment: Operating System and version?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia  Ubuntu 18.04.2